# Classifying an algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a set $S$, with two operations defined on it: $+$ and $*$.

e.g. S is the set of polynomials of degree k. The + and * are usual polynomial addition and multiplication.

$(S,+)$ is an abelian group. Call $0$ its identity.

$S$ is not closed under $*$, i.e. for some $a,b\in S,\;a*b\notin S$.

$S$ has an identiy w.r.t $*$ except for the element $0$.

$*$ is commutative and associative

$*$ distributes over $+$ but $+$ doesn't distribute over $*$.

What algebraic structure is $(S, +, *)$?

Comment: If $ab$ is not in $S$, where is it?

Comment: @AnneBauval I interpret it as being a partial function $S\times S \to S$. Consider division in the integers. Where is $\frac 34$? Where is $\frac50$?

Comment: So, if $ab$ is not in $S$ then $ab$ does not exist at all? Let the OP tell us.

Comment: Does "S has an identiy w.r.t * *except for the element 0*" mean that $0*1\ne0$?

Comment: The other properties of $*$ need to be defined more precisely if $*$ is only defined on a subset of $S\times S.$ Anyway, I doubt such a structure has a name.

Comment: There do exist certain algebraic structures based on partially defined binary operations. [Groupoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid) are such a structure, although that's just a single operation, not two operations as in this post. But unless this particular structure has interesting examples and/or applications, I do not see why one would expect it to fit into some existing classification.

Comment: Note that by definition, a (binary) operation on $S$ is a function $S\times S\to S$. If you have a function $*$ defined on $S\times S$, but $a*b$ need not be in $S$ when $a,b\in S$, then you cannot call $*$ an "operation" on $S$. So what you describe cannot be an "algebraic structure", which requires *operations*.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not "closed" how can one say it is associative?

If $ab\notin S$, then how can $(ab)c=a(bc)$ when the thing on the lefthand side is not defined?

But let's have a broader conversation.

An algebraic structure on a set $S$ is characterized by $n$-ary operations **on the set**, meaning functions $S^n\to S$, and axioms that interrelate these operations.

This, anyhow, is the prevalent point of view for most of algebra, as formalized in [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra).

As such, I would say your description does not qualify as a "bona fide"  algebraic structure on $S$.

Perhaps it used to be common to think of "composing two things" as something abstract without specifying what the composition would become, as if the notion of composition were some sort of primitive idea.  From that viewpoint one *would* need to go further and say where it would be.  That would let one consider something else like the real inner product (a function from $V\times V\to \mathbb R$) as a sort of operation "on $S$" too.

But nowadays, as we mostly operate in ZF or something similar that defines functions as we do, the codomain is part of what a function is, and so there's no need to say something like "composition of two elements of $S$ that satisfies closure" (lies in $S$) or "composition of two elements of $S$ that lies in $\mathbb R$", you just say "function $S\times S\to S$" or  "function $S\times S\to \mathbb R$."

Now one may ask, "Ok then, so is an inner product space not an algebraic structure?  The operation involved returns things in $\mathbb R$."  Insofar as it is an abelian group, it is an algebraic structure, and the inner product does define a sort of data, but I would argue that the role of this extra data is to cut out *other* (bona fide) algebraic structures.  If one knows about such things, one would say that the inner product is a useful invariant whose preservation we could study.

For example, a vector space has an associated group (the group of invertible linear transformations on the vector space) but you need an inner product on a real vector space to define its orthogonal linear transformation group.  The structure data on the vector space goes into defining an algebraic structure of interest.

---

Honestly my opinion is to just abolish the notion of "closure axiom for operations" in favor of using straightforward function notation, and use "closure" instead where it is useful (when discussing subsets of a set with an operation on it.)

To rephrase that, saying an operation $X\times X\to ?$ "satisfies a closure operation" is a poor proxy for just saying "function $X\times X\to X$ and is not extensible to accomodate other common situations (like $X\times X \to \mathbb R$) so it seems like this functional description is a more robust foundation.

Comment: Three cheers for :"just abolish the notion of "closure axiom for operations"!!!

Comment: You might be interested in [groupoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid), where associativity and non-closure exist in peaceful harmony.

Comment: Even for groupoids, one predefines where the result of the composition lands, which I think is the analogue for "closure" for that context.  The key thing that groupids bring, I think, is partial-definedness.

Comment: There is a theory of "partial algebras", where some of the (partial) operations are only defined on certain tuples. One has to be careful, though, as for example it is no longer true that the image of a partial subalgebra needs to be a partial subalgebra under a homomorphism...

Comment: I've given an example in the edited version of the question.

Comment: @Ekalabya You might be interested in [graded algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_algebra) where multiplication is not "closed" within grades, but it does behave compatibly with polynomial multiplication (that is to say, it is predictable where the product will go.)